# Where to add my merchant gateway using ubercart?

Tags: ubercart

I am trying to figure out how to add the gateway of my merchant so I can accept credit card payment.

I have given a URL by my merchant and I can redirect to this URL easily using my own PHP code, but I can't find a way to integrate it using Ubercart.

Example gateway is https://test.mymerchantgateway.com/ECN/eng/payment/payForm.jsp.

So that when my customer checkout it will be redirected to the url above and when the payment is successful it will return to my website using the "successUrl" like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="successUrl" value="http://mydomain.com/success.php">
```

I am using Drupal 6, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of modules that actually does this. You will need to do some custom coding and integrating with Ubercart. It's been a while since I did this and it also depends on your Ubercart/Drupal version. But you can checkout the quickpay module for drupal 6 integration example.

The typical way of doing these kinds of things, is to create a form and auto post it with javascript to the payment gateway url with all the params needed. It's up to you to send the correct params along and up to the gateway to redirect back. But answering those questions won't be drupal or ubercart related.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply. I have already created a module to redirect the payment to my merchant URL. My problem now is the return url to my cart. My question now is on how to complete the order after payment. Here's some question I have on stackoverflow: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832519/what-is-the-return-url-of-ubercart-after-successful-payment)

Comment: @jaypabs What version are you using 6/7?

Comment: i'm using drupal version 6.

Comment: @jaypabs Updated my answer. Your problem is most likely not really related to Drupal or Ubercart, but instead the payment gateway itself and their APIs.